# Use instr to scan string if start with

Tags: string, vba, parsing

I am passing one parameter to a function, where the parameter will start with either 'Error One' or 'Error Two'.

Example:

```
Error One: A
Error One: B
Error Two: A
Error Two: B
```

So inside the function, I need a condition to check what the passed in string **starts with** that will dictate the actions.

I was trying to use the INSTR function

```
IF (INSTR(p_msg, 'Error One') = 'Error One') ....
```

But is not working.
I am not putting start_position as I see it defaults to 1.
How do I use INSTR function to check what the string starts with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) returns the **position** of the search string within the string or zero if not found; it doesn't return the string itself. I've also found it beneficial to wrap a `CBool` around the function to explicitly make it a True/False.

```
if CBool(INSTR(p_msg, "Error One")) Then
```

Note that this is not always a **start with** scenario; merely that one sub-string is **within** the other. If it has to **start with** your search string, the `Like` operator might be more appropriate.

```
if p_msg LIKE "Error One*" Then
```

Note the asterisk wildcard character. I don't know why you were using single quotes (e.g. *ticks*) but only double quotes are used in VBA to distinguish text.

You might also want to look at a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) instead of a number of nested `If` statements.

Comment: oh ok, so I could use the InStr function to check if the string is NOT returned in any position...
So something like:

IF (INSTR(p_msg, 'Error One') <> 0) ....

Comment: It doesn't return the string. If it is found, it will return the non-zero position where it is found; if it is not found it will return zero. In the case where it starts the string then it will return **1**. Yes, you could check to see if the return value is non-zero.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications